# MVC UML class diagram multilanguage C# & Javascript angular

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, model-view-controller, uml

I need to make a uml class diagram and i think it needs to be an mvc one. The problem is i have never made a mvc class diagram and can't seem to figure something out.

which methods needs to be in on the view side and which on the controller?
The best I came up with is that methods that are called from a button in html/angular need to be in the view "package" as method callers, 
and the rest on controller(so c# and javascript methods)

Comment: Another useful link ► https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381412(v=vs.108).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically MVC mean Model View Controller. **Model** should contain all domain specific logic. **View** is presentation layer, so only stuff related with the presentation to the user. **Controller** should be a glue between domain and presentation, controller should not contain any complicated domain specific logic, just basic stuff to glue domain with presentation.

For more details check [**Model View Controller Design Patterns**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42830/Model-View-Controller-Model-View-Presenter-and-Mod)

Comment: Does that mean that i was on the right track?, methods that show data and send user input need to be in view as caller or sender methods and the rest in controller? If not is it possible you can give me a small example?

Comment: I think you are. I edited post so you can look at example to get some feeling. Good luck.

Comment: thanks for your help, but i can't seem to find the example in the link. was expecting a diagram or is there something else in there that can help me?

Comment: Oh I see, I added the new link.

Comment: thanks again for the help. Already knew about that link just needed a confirmation for my hunch.